# Can we override a method in a swift class which is not the subclass of it?

Tags: ios, swift, function

Hi guys please help me, My question is i have two classes. Class A is a 
custom view and class C is a view controller. Now how can i override a 
function in Class A (Custom View) from Class C (ViewController)

```
Class A : B
    {
     func testMethod()
      {
       //code block
      }
    }

 Class C : D 
   {
     override func testMethod()
     {

     }
   }
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense doing this...I think you should read more about subclassing.

Comment: The term `override` means, adding extra functionality to the method which is defined in `superClass` If you don't have method in super class you can not override it.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense, you override methods from a superclass, you can't override methods for totally different classes.

You can just name the method the same (remove `override` keyword)